# Creating thumbnail from local video in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, video-capture

How to create thumbnail in swift from a local video file ?

For example if the video file path is located here :

`file:///Users/Dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F33222DF-D8F0-448B-A127-C5B03C64D0DC/data/Containers/Data/Application/4BC62DBF-0108-453C-9324-5BC0E356FE24/tmp/trim.059D11E6-F0EF-43DB-9E97-CA4F1F95D6B6.MOV`

Thank you.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Translated with some edits from:

[First frame of a video using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221242/first-frame-of-a-video-using-avfoundation)

```
    var err: NSError? = nil
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/that/long/path"), options: nil)
    let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    let cgImage = imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil, error: &err)
    // !! check the error before proceeding
    let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
    // lay out this image view, or if it already exists, set its image property to uiImage
```

Comment: How can I get Thumbnail from duration (10 sec to 15 sec) using any video URL?

Comment: @AnandGautam I'll take a wild guess and say you provide a different CMTime?

Comment: how to get a system cameraRoll video thumbnail?

Answer (score 75):

BaseZen's answer translated **Swift 3** / **Swift 4**

You need to set the location of the video you want to make a thumbnail of as the url asset path, like:

Don't forget to `import AVFoundation`

```
func generateThumbnail(path: URL) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path, options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return thumbnail
    } catch let error {
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

For everyone having issues with this I have created the following drop in example hosted on [**Github**](https://github.com/davidseek/ThumbnailTestProject)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code, don't know why but its taking 10-15 secs to display the preview. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @vivektakrani open a new thread and provide your code and logic

Comment: since you've already got an answer, i have just upvoted it for you so you're break even again

Comment: Very good. Sorry for the noob question, but what kind of video format are supported?

Comment: Error generating thumbnail: Cannot Open on iOS 11. Additional usage description is already there.

Comment: @sharadchauhan I have created the following GIT project for you: https://github.com/davidseek/ThumbnailTestProject check it out

Comment: How can I get Thumbnail from duration (10 sec to 15 sec) using any video URL?

Comment: Not with this approach. You would need to create a function to get a sub video for your desired duration and then get a thumbnail from that sub video.

Answer (score 25):

This is a cleaned up version of David's answer and tested against iOS 11 / Swift 4.x.

Please note the different calls for handling the initial time based on which version of Swift you are using.

```
func generateThumbnail(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        // Select the right one based on which version you are using
        // Swift 4.2
        let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: .zero,
                                                     actualTime: nil)
        // Swift 4.0
        let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: kCMTimeZero,
                                                     actualTime: nil)


        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        return nil
    }
}
```

1. Creates an `AVURLAsset` from the provided `URL`
2. Creates an `AVAssetImageGenerator` using the newly created `AVURLAsset`, is responsible for making the thumbnail
3. [appliesPreferredTrackTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1390616-appliespreferredtracktransform) informs the generator to apply the matrix to the thumbnail generation. The default value is false.
4. Attempts to create a `CGImage` at the first frame of the video track
5. Creates a `UIImage` using the newly created CGImage & returns it
6. If the image generation step fails, an error is caught and presented to the console along with a nil UIImage

Answer (score 13):

BaseZen's answer translated to Swift 2:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

do {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/that/long/path"), options: nil)
    let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
    let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
    // lay out this image view, or if it already exists, set its image property to uiImage
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: sure, and `var err` is irrelevant now.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed it.

Comment: I found that some of my thumbnails did not have the same orientation as the original videos.  Setting imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform to true fixed that.

Comment: How can I get Thumbnail from duration (10 sec to 15 sec) using any video URL?

Answer (score 13):

It's better to write less and simple code for understanding.
This is what I convert the solutions in Swift (3.1 ... 5.2)

```
import AVFoundation

func imagePreview(from moviePath: URL, in seconds: Double) -> UIImage? {
    let timestamp = CMTime(seconds: seconds, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: moviePath)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    guard let imageRef = try? generator.copyCGImage(at: timestamp, actualTime: nil) else {
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
}
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5.3**

As an alternative to other answers, with slight modification I decided to make an URL extension.

```
import AVFoundation

extension URL {
    func generateThumbnail() -> UIImage? {
        do {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: self)
            let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            
            // Swift 5.3
            let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: .zero,
                                                         actualTime: nil)

            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let image = someURL.generateThumbnail()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you generate a thumbnail (first frame) of a video in swift 5:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let video = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sampleVideo", ofType: "mov")!))
        let thumbnailGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: video)
    
        do
        {
            let cgImage = try thumbnailGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1), actualTime: nil)
            let UiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            imageView.image = UiImage
        }
        catch
        { print(error) }
    
    }

}
```

In this example the video name is sampleVideo.mov (change the file url to the name of your video file), make sure you import the video into your local Xcode project and add it to your app's target.

I have make a youtube explaining this [here](https://youtu.be/ufx6Pzzcjtc)

Answer (score 0):

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectoryWithDate(tempImage:UIImage, block : @escaping (_ url: URL?) -> Void ){

    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

    let random : String =  randomString(length: 5)

    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(String(format:"CPImage%@.png",random))
    do { try tempImage.pngData()?.write(to: fileURL) }
    catch { block(nil) }
    block(fileURL)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Kingfisher** to generate the thumbnail.

**Note:-** It will handle all the cache work for you.

**Usage:-**

**Step 1**

```
import Kingfisher
```

**Step 2**

```
guard let url = URL(string: videoUrlString) else { return }
self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: AVAssetImageDataProvider(assetURL: url, seconds: 1))
```

Here is the link of Kingfisher SDK

- https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

**Note:- It will work fine with latest version of kingfisher/ higher or equals to version 7.2.3**

Answer (score 0):

From **iOS 13.0+**, there is a built-in class [QLThumbnailGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/qlthumbnailgenerator) available for generating thumbnails. The best part is, it's able to generate thumbnails for most file types like image, video, PDF, gif, etc...

### Sample code

```
import QuickLook

func generateThumbnailRepresentation(url: URL) {
    
    let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    
    // Create the thumbnail request.
    let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: url,
                                               size: size,
                                               scale: scale,
                                               representationTypes: .thumbnail)
    
    // Retrieve the singleton instance of the thumbnail generator and generate the thumbnails.
    let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
    generator.generateRepresentations(for: request) { (thumbnail, type, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if thumbnail == nil || error != nil {
                // Handle the error case gracefully.
                
            } else {
                // Display the thumbnail that you created.
                
                // Just saving the thumbnail in Photos for testing
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(thumbnail!.uiImage, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/creating-quick-look-thumbnails-to-preview-files-in-your-app)