# How to get thumbnail image of video picked from UIPickerViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I access the video:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
        let video = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)
    }
}
```

That `video` I would like to show the user in my controller (I do not mean `UIDocumentInteractionController` to preview this). I need a thumbnail of that video, and then assign this to `UIImageView`. Is it possible?

Comment: Look at this post: [Creating thumbnail from local video in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779150/creating-thumbnail-from-local-video-in-swift) Regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest answer:

```
import AVFoundation

private func thumbnailForVideoAtURL(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {

    let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

    var time = asset.duration
    time.value = min(time.value, 2)

    do {
        let imageRef = try assetImageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    } catch {
        print("error")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thumbnail generated successfully but image rotated to 90 degree.

Comment: Checking with youtube urls and getting this error: `Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb4a3c04870 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12939 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}`

Comment: @Pushpendra tam getting the same error how did u solve it

Comment: Thumbnail image is rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: To fix the thumbnail rotation, I used: `assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true` as it is default false.

Answer (score 7):

**Here's SWIFT 3.0 using extension**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

import SystemConfiguration

extension AVAsset{
    var videoThumbnail:UIImage?{

        let assetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: self)
        assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

        var time = self.duration
        time.value = min(time.value, 2)

        do {
            let imageRef = try assetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            let thumbNail = UIImage.init(cgImage: imageRef)


            print("Video Thumbnail genertated successfuly".DubugSuccess())

            return thumbNail

        } catch {

            print("error getting thumbnail video".DubugError(),error.localizedDescription)
            return nil


        }

    }
}
```

Then simply from anywhere you have access to **AVAsset/URL**:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
        let video = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)

        //Create AVAsset from url
        let ass = AVAsset(url:videoURL)

        if let videoThumbnail = ass.videoThumbnail{
          print("Success")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you @Jad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a thumbnail with this method:

```
import AVFoundation

func generateThumnail(url : NSURL) -> UIImage?{
    let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time        : CMTime = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
    let img         : CGImageRef
    do {
        try img = assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        let frameImg: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: img)
        return frameImg
    } catch {

    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for AiOsN and the way how to fix image rotation.
You just need to change this line of code:

```
return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
```

to this one:

```
return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef scale: 1.0 , orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
```

and the image will show you correct rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [QLThumbnailGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/qlthumbnailgenerator) for generating thumbnails. It's available from iOS 13.0+ and supports a wide range of file types including video files.

### Code:

```
import QuickLook

func generateThumbnailRepresentation(url: URL) {
    
    let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    
    // Create the thumbnail request.
    let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: url,
                                               size: size,
                                               scale: scale,
                                               representationTypes: .thumbnail)
    
    // Retrieve the singleton instance of the thumbnail generator and generate the thumbnails.
    let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared
    generator.generateRepresentations(for: request) { (thumbnail, type, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if thumbnail == nil || error != nil {
                // Handle the error case gracefully.
                
            } else {
                // Display the thumbnail that you created.
                
                // Just saving the thumbnail in Photos for testing
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(thumbnail!.uiImage, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[For more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/creating-quick-look-thumbnails-to-preview-files-in-your-app).