# iOS Swift: Set video preview

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I'm using avplayer to display videos in my swift application. It works perfectly but I want to set the preview of each video (display a specific image).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got the AVAsset, you can use AVAssetImageGenerator to get an image at a specified time.[Check out this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779150/creating-thumbnail-from-local-video-in-swift)

If you're using the Photos framework to get videos from the users camera roll, Apple provides a PHCacheImageManager.requestImage to get a thumbnail image for videos.