# Get thumbnail from a video url online and display on a cell

Tags: ios, web

How can I get the thumbnail image from a video stored online URL? I need the thumbnails so that I could display them in a collectionview.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: try this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4330647/3543861

Comment: I'll try this out, thank you! @MSU_Bulldog

Comment: Hi! Do you have an idea? @TonyHensler

Comment: I can play a remote video on AVPlayer with a URL, and I've been searching how to grab a frame and display it on an image view. But I keep coming across dead ends @TonyHensler

Comment: @TonyHensler - can you please help me out how it is possible. I want to do the same in cell. AVAssetImageGenerator hangs the UI. and I want to display it as user comes on that screen.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog - can you please help me out how it is possible. I want to do the same in cell. AVAssetImageGenerator hangs the UI. and I want to display it as user comes on that screen.

Comment: @KennyBatista did you find any solution for this? if yes then please let me know.

Comment: @Urmi if you have a question, please post a new question instead of adding comments to this one.

Comment: Hey @Urmi , check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779150/creating-thumbnail-from-local-video-in-swift . Let me know if you get it to work, if not i'll send you own source code.