# How to generate thumbnail from Video url?

Tags: ios, swift

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40987452/5501940), I am using below code to generate thumbnail from Video URL:

```
//MARK: - - Generate Thumbnail
func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {

    do {

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path, options: nil)

        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        let uiImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)

        return uiImage


    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

but it is throwing an  error:

> Error generating thumbnail: The operation could not be completed

Comment: Where does CMTimeMake(0, 1) come from?

Comment: I am directly passing it

Comment: Your code is perfectly working in my case. Check your URL and video file which is in file manager. Is video actually there or not?

Comment: i have used youtube url also for this

Comment: @SandipGill, url to the video page or to the video file? Can you show us this url?

Comment: This is my url i am getting it from my directory.

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/007D2DC0-99F5-4C13-90D6-B58E8BB61E14/Documents/video.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for generating thumb image from video url.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: "**your url of video**")
    let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
     assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMake(1, 2)
    let img = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
    if img != nil {
    let frameImg  = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    // assign your image to UIImageView
                    })
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey I have also used same logic for thumbnail of video.

```
        do {
            let videoUrl = "Url"

            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)

            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)

            // Rotate image before proceeding
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: CGFloat(1.0), orientation: .right)

            image = uiImage

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print("Error occurred: \(error)")
        }
```

It works for me. After getting `CGImage` image orientation was not proper so made orientation proper. See if it works for you.

Comment: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/007D2DC0-99F5-4C13-90D6-B58E8BB61E14/Documents/video.mp4

this is my file url